# Record multiple input marker clicks with Shiny and leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm working on an app that displays information based of sites that you can choose with an interactive map through leaflet, but I want to be able to choose multiple sites. Right now with using input$map_marker_click I only generate the information based off the last site clicked. I want to generate information based off of multiple sites as chosen by the user.

I've tried declaring an empty vector first and then using insput$map_marker_click to add to that vector but every time I click on another marker my vector is set to empty again and I lose the data from my last marker click.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a reactive object to store persistent data in your app server.
Example to store simple clicks on the map :

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "reset", label = "Reset"),
  leafletOutput("map"),
  dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # initialise reactive to store clicks
  clicked <- reactiveValues(markers = setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0)), c("id", "lat", "lng")))
  
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$map_click,{
    # append last click to previous clicks
    clicked$markers <- rbind(
      clicked$markers,
      data.frame(id=nrow(clicked$markers)+1, lat = input$map_click$lat, lng = input$map_click$lng))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    clicked$markers
  })
  
  # reset clicked data
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    clicked$markers <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0)), c("id", "lat", "lng"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```